# UICollectionView with Custom Cells Not Scrolling or Rendering Properly

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Example:

[image]

I am laying out everything in code (no `storyboard`).  I have a `UIViewController` with a `UICollectionView`(this collectionview is normally positioned at the top, but I've moved it down so it's easier to see).  This `UICollectionView` is called `topTabView` and it uses `tabCell`s.  The `tabCell`s are just vessels for a custom button class called `TabButton`.  I suspect there is more than one issue here since not only is the scrolling choppy, but the tabs are moving and going out of order as well.

ViewController:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    let tabCellId = "tabCellId"

    var topTabView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tabHeight = view.frame.height / 45

        //self.view.frame.height / 27 is a hack for the top layout guide
        let topLayoutGuideY = view.frame.height / 27

        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal

        topTabView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 300, width: self.view.frame.width - tabHeight, height: tabHeight), collectionViewLayout: layout)
        topTabView.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: topTabView.frame.width, height: topTabView.frame.height)

        topTabView.dataSource = self
        topTabView.delegate = self
        topTabView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        topTabView.register(tabCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: tabCellId)           
        view.addSubview(topTabView)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 15  //just for testing
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: tabCellId, for: indexPath) as! tabCell

        //cell.button.setTitle(Tabs.SharedInstance.tabsToPersist[indexPath.item].tabName, for: .normal)
        cell.button.setTitle("test" + String(indexPath.item), for: .normal)

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: topTabView.frame.width / 7, height: topTabView.frame.height)
    }
}
```

tabCell:

```
class tabCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var button: TabButton

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        button = TabButton(frame: frame)
        button.setTitle("Tutorial", for: .normal)

        super.init(frame: frame)

        print(self.frame)
        addSubview(button)
    }
    //Left Out Required Init Coder for Space
}
```

TabButton:

```
class TabButton: UIButton {

    // Inits
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupButton()
    }
    //Removed Required Init Coder for Space
    //Overrides
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        //Long Custom Draw Function, confirmed working fine
    }

    func setupButton() {
        backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        self.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 9)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hii, can you please try with increasing a height of collectionview and check the same issue is producing .?

Comment: @YogeshPatel height of the collectionView or height of the cells?  Isn't the height of the collection view set when I initialize it with a frame?  I have also implemented the size for item at index Path Function

Comment: No CollectionView Height means your tabHeight

Comment: I don't follow.  Neither the CollectionView nor the TabCell have a height parameter

Comment: i am talking about this height 
topTabView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 300, width: self.view.frame.width - tabHeight, height: "tabHeight"),  <- TabHeight .?Got

Comment: I am also having this issue, have you figured this out?

Answer (score 0):

Please do clipsToBounds true

```
topTabView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Please check this video is it ok or i forgot to do anything please let me know

[image]

Comment: This didn't change anything :/

Comment: Please check this onces

Comment: I checked, the video seems correct, but clips to bounds = true didn't fix my problem

Comment: Okay i just copy your code and add this topTabView.clipsToBounds = true below the code topTabView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

Comment: You add complete code here because this is working for me .?

Comment: clipsToBounds = True is before addSubView

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194510/discussion-between-gabe-spound-and-yogesh-patel).